# Как перехватить нажатие клавиши?

Tags: linux, консоль, rust

Здравствуйте! Как я могу прехватить нажатие клавиши в консоли под Linux? Например, нажата клавиша `'W'` - напечатать `"Нажата клавиша W!"`.

Comment: посмотрите, как *keylogger* для консоли реализован на *c*, и реализуйте на *rust-е*.

Comment: ссылку забыл вставить: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkl/

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! К сожаленью, у меня не достаточно знаний Си и Rust, чтобы переписать keylogger.

Comment: Учись, что ещё. StackOverflow не пишет код за кого-то.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример из библиотеки Rust-SDL2:

https://github.com/AngryLawyer/rust-sdl2/blob/master/examples/keyboard-state.rs

```
extern crate sdl2;

use sdl2::event::Event;
use sdl2::keyboard::Keycode;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::time::Duration;

pub fn main() {
    let sdl_context = sdl2::init().unwrap();
    let video_subsystem = sdl_context.video().unwrap();

    let _window = video_subsystem.window("Keyboard", 800, 600)
        .position_centered()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    let mut events = sdl_context.event_pump().unwrap();

    let mut prev_keys = HashSet::new();

    'running: loop {
        for event in events.poll_iter() {
            if let Event::Quit {..} = event {
                break 'running;
            };
        }

        // Create a set of pressed Keys.
        let keys = events.keyboard_state().pressed_scancodes().filter_map(Keycode::from_scancode).collect();

        // Get the difference between the new and old sets.
        let new_keys = &keys - &prev_keys;
        let old_keys = &prev_keys - &keys;

        if !new_keys.is_empty() || !old_keys.is_empty() {
            println!("new_keys: {:?}\told_keys:{:?}", new_keys, old_keys);
        }

        prev_keys = keys;

        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    }
}
```

По-моему как раз то, что вам нужно.